# Can't install mongoose via npm - dependency failed es6-promise 3.0.2

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm, mean-stack, es6-promise

I'm currently trying to set up a MEAN stack using a tutorial, but I got some dependency problems, and as I'm a total newby in nodejs and mondodb, I can't get it fixed.

I'm using this tutorial: https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial

Setup:

```
Windows 7 x64
MongoDB 2.6.11 (The tutorial require 2.6.7, so I didn't install the v3)
node -v: v0.12.5
npm -v: 2.11.2
```

The problem:
When I try to run

```
npm install --save mongoose
```

I have this error:

```
npm ERR! version not found: es6-promise@3.0.2
```

If I run

```
npm install es6-promise
```

It sets in my package.json the v2.3.0, and mongoos still doesn't install

```
"es6-promise": "^2.3.0",
```

If I try to force it at the ^3.0.0 and run npm install

```
"es6-promise": "^3.0.0",
```

it says:

```
npm ERR! notarget ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","1.0.0","2.0.0","2.0.1","2.1.0","2.1.1","2.2.0","2.3.0"]
```

And I'm pretty much stuck here. 
Do you have any ideas why I can't get the correct version of es6-promise?
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

[upgrade node here](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows)

upgrade your node and npm check this link will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, it updated my npm version to 3.3.6, but I still have a similar error while trying to install mongoose:

    npm ERR! No compatible version found: es6-promise@3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by downgrading the version of mongoose to "^3.8.22" (The es6-promise dependency was added to the 4.0)

It's not the perfect solution, but it will do the trick for now. I will find out why it didn't work once I'll have more experience with npm